# Как вставить 2-ой вектор перед первым?

Tags: c++, вектор

Как вставить второй вектор перед первым? `push_front` не работает!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int k = 1;
    int s = 0;
    int a[50];
    vector<int>v1(5, 1);
    v1.clear();
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(5);
    v1.push_back(4);
    v1.push_back(6);
    vector<int>v2(5, 1);
    v2.clear();
    v2.push_back(7);
    v2.push_back(6);
    v2.push_back(0);
    v2.push_back(0);
    v2.push_back(9);
    cout << "Ishodnii Vector" << endl;
    cout << "Razmer v1: " << v1.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
        cout << " v1[" << i << "]=" << v1[i];
    for (int i = 0; i <v1.size(); i++)
        s += v1[i];
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <v1.size(); i++)

        if (v1[i] == 1) v2.push_back(i);
    for (int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
    {
        v2.push_back(i);

        k++;
    }
    cout << "\nRezultat Zadania" << endl;
    cout << "Razmer v1: " << v1.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
        cout << " v1[" << i << "]=" << v1[i];
    cout << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Что означает «не работает»?

Comment: И да, попробуйте `insert`.

Comment: если вам нужно часто вставлять в середину, то может вы зря выбрали `vector` или лучше добавить 1 в _конец_ 2?

Comment: [vector::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)

Comment: `v2.push_back(v1[i]);`

Comment: Переставить вывод местами?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я, а потом потерял аккаунт и не смог восстановиться. Не один из предложенных советов не помог.

Comment: Holy Guacamole,  а почему  бы просто не добавлять в конец второго ? типо v2.push_back(v1[i])

Comment: @Kirill21 потому что в задании требуется именно в начало первого

Comment: а почему вы не попробовали `insert`?

Comment: @Holy Guacamole  тогда измените ваш вопрос. Из вашего вопроса это не понятно

Comment: @Holy Guacamole, https://ideone.com/rQEhPs  Вот тут рабочий код.

Comment: @Kirill21 спасибо все работает!!

Comment: @Kirill21, добавьте ответом.

Comment: тот же вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536298

Comment: @alexanderbarakin объединил вопросы, теперь один

Answer (score 3):

Решение из [комментария Kirill21](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536157/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC#comment673905_536157)

https://ideone.com/rQEhPs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v1{1,3,5,4,6};
    vector<int> v2{7,6,0,0,9};
    for(int i=0, k=v2.size()-1 ;i<v2.size();++i)
    {
        v1.insert(v1.begin(),v2[k--]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< v1.size();++i)
    {
        std::cout<<v1[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```