# ВТОРОЙ вектор встал перед ПЕРВЫМ

Tags: c++

Помогите сделать так, чтобы ВТОРОЙ вектор встал перед ПЕРВЫМ.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int k = 1;
    int s = 0;
    int a[50];
    vector<int>v1(5, 1);
    v1.clear();
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(5);
    v1.push_back(4);
    v1.push_back(6);
    vector<int>v2(5, 1);
    v2.clear();
    v2.push_back(7);
    v2.push_back(6);
    v2.push_back(0);
    v2.push_back(0);
    v2.push_back(9);
    cout << "Ishodnii Vector" << endl;
    cout << "Razmer v1: " << v1.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
        cout << " v1[" << i << "]=" << v1[i];
    for (int i = 0; i <v1.size(); i++)
        s += v1[i];
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <v1.size(); i++)

        if (v1[i] == 1) v2.push_back(i);
    for (int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
    {
        v2.push_back(i);

        k++;
    }
    cout << "\nRezultat Zadania" << endl;
    cout << "Razmer v1: " << v1.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
        cout << " v1[" << i << "]=" << v1[i];
    cout << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Вы вроде уже задавали этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536157/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC  (или ваш однокурсник, с таким же ником)